# MySQL Analytic function

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table of below format

```
SurveyCity ProductName SurveybyCompany1 SurveybyCompany2
City1      Chocolate     Good           Good
City1      Caramel       Good           Bad
City1      Vanilla       Bad            Good
City1      Butterscoth   Bad            Bad
City2      Chocolate     Good           Good
City2      Caramel       Good           Bad
City2      Vanilla       Bad            Good
City2      Butterscoth   Bad            Bad
```

I want a report like this

```
Company1    Company2    Caramel Chocolate Vanilla Butterscoth   
Good        Good        0          2        0       0
Good        Bad         2          0        0       0
Bad         Good        0          0        2       0
Bad         Bad         0          0        0       2
```

I am writing 4 queries like below to generate this report

```
select productname,count(*) from table where surveybycompany1='Good' and surveybycompany2='Good' group by productname
```

My doubt is, is it possible to produce this entire output table in one query. I am using MySQL DB

Please provide your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum`, `if` and `group by`

```
select SurveybyCompany1 Company1, 
SurveybyCompany2 Company2, 
sum(if(ProductName = 'Caramel', 1, 0)) as Caramel, 
sum(if(ProductName = 'Chocolate', 1, 0)) as Chocolate, 
sum(if(ProductName = 'Vanilla', 1, 0)) Vanilla, 
sum(if(ProductName = 'Butterscoth', 1, 0)) Butterschoth 
from your_table group by Company1, Company2
order by Company1 desc, Company2 desc;
```

output:

```
+----------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| Company1 | Company2 | Caramel | Chocolate | Vanilla | Butterschoth |
+----------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| Good     | Good     |       0 |         2 |       0 |            0 |
| Good     | Bad      |       2 |         0 |       0 |            0 |
| Bad      | Good     |       0 |         0 |       2 |            0 |
| Bad      | Bad      |       0 |         0 |       0 |            2 |
+----------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+
```